# Не получается установить composer глобально

Tags: php, linux, composer

Выполняю все согласно инструкции сайта https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Файл лежит в `/usr/local/bin`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при вводе команды composer в терминал выдает ошибку

> Could not open input file: `composer.phar`

Answer (score 2):

У вас он лежит как файл `composer`, выполняйте команды вот так:

```
composer update
```

Не указывая `.phar`
Так же проверьте чтоб он был запускаемым:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: Оказывается я забыл терминал просто напросто перезапустить. Недавно на linux, но все равно спасибо